# MySQL order by - does not sort properly

Tags: mysql, csv, sorting

This seems so simple... I am running a SQL query to output to a CSV. I want to sort by the first column in the query, then the second. It's critical for the program that uses the CSV as input, because it is looking for changes in these values to trigger writes, having accumulated data from all rows with the same values in those two fields. I suspect it has to do with the fact that I'm outputting to a CSV, as I explain below.

I started with:

```
SELECT claim_no, form_no, ...
ORDER BY claim_no, form_no
```

Both claim_no and form_no are VARCHAR fields but contain only digits. The output file was not sorted, except coincidentally (probably in the approximate order of insertion).

I considered the possibility that form_no could be NULL, which could affect the behaviour, as the tables are joined with a LEFT OUTER JOIN. So I changed it to:

```
SELECT claim_no, form_no, ...
ORDER BY claim_no, IFNULL(form_no, '0')
```

Still no luck. I looked for any ideas in SO, and it appeared that perhaps CASTing to INT would help, so then I had:

```
SELECT claim_no, form_no, ...
ORDER BY CAST(claim_no AS UNSIGNED), CAST(IFNULL(form_no, '0') AS UNSIGNED)
```

Nope. Here's an example from the CSV file:

```
...
"5799", "9823638", ...
"5800", "9824370", ...
"5800", "9824056", ...
...
"4258", "9728616", ...
"4258", "9728782", ...
...
"4258", "9719766", ...
...
```

But if I run this query in the MySQL command line:

```
select claim_no, form_no from claim left outer join transportation_claim on claim_id = claim.id where claim_no = '5800' order by claim_no, form_no;
```

... I get a properly sorted result for claim #5800.

Unless someone knows why this is happening, I'm going to have to change the program that uses the CSV file as input - something I would rather not do.

For completeness, here is the entire query. The CSV file has 340k lines, so you'll forgive me for not including it.

```
(SELECT
    'claim_no', 'document_no', 'date_received', 'toll_type', 'toll_amount', 'driver_amount',
    'downtime_amount', 'vehicle_amount', 'claimed_amount', 'distance', 'generator_reg_no',
    'transporter_reg_no', 'city_name', 'distance_rate',
    'plt_count', 'plt_weight', 'mt_count', 'mt_weight', 'ag_count', 'ag_weight', 'ls_count', 'ls_weight')
UNION
(SELECT 
    claim_no,
    IF(form_no IS NULL, CONCAT('0000', claim_no), form_no),
    IF(transportation_claim.date_received IS NULL, 'No Date Received', transportation_claim.date_received),
    IF(toll_type IS NULL, 'Barge', toll_type),
    IF(toll_amount IS NULL, 0, toll_amount), 
    IF(driver_amount IS NULL, 0, driver_amount),
    IF(downtime_amount IS NULL, 0, downtime_amount),
    IF(vehicle_amount IS NULL, 0, vehicle_amount),
    IF(claimed_amount IS NULL, 0, IF(toll_amount IS NULL, claimed_amount, claimed_amount - toll_amount)),
    IF(distance IS NULL, 0, distance),
    IF(generator.registration_no IS NULL, '7000', generator.registration_no),
    IF(transporter.registration_no IS NULL, '700', transporter.registration_no),
    IF(city.name IS NULL, 'No City', city.name),
    IF(distance_rate IS NULL, 0, distance_rate),
    IF(plt_count IS NULL, 0, plt_count), IF(plt_weight IS NULL, 0, plt_weight),
    IF(mt_count IS NULL, 0, mt_count), IF(mt_weight IS NULL, 0, mt_weight),
    IF(ag_count IS NULL, 0, ag_count), IF(ag_weight IS NULL, 0, ag_weight),
    IF(ls_count IS NULL, 0, ls_count), IF(ls_weight IS NULL, 0, ls_weight)
    INTO OUTFILE 'collections.csv'
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    FROM claim
    LEFT OUTER JOIN transportation_claim ON claim.id = transportation_claim.claim_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN participant AS transporter ON transporter.id = transporter_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN participant AS generator ON generator.id = generator_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN city ON city.id = generator_city_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT SUM(count) AS plt_count, SUM(weight) AS plt_weight, transportation_claim_id
        FROM transportation_claim_detail
        INNER JOIN revenue_product ON revenue_product.id = revenue_product_id
        WHERE revenue_product.product_code = 'PLT'
        GROUP BY transportation_claim_id) AS plt ON plt.transportation_claim_id = transportation_claim.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT SUM(count) AS mt_count, SUM(weight) AS mt_weight, transportation_claim_id
        FROM transportation_claim_detail
        INNER JOIN revenue_product ON revenue_product.id = revenue_product_id
        WHERE revenue_product.product_code = 'MT'
        GROUP BY transportation_claim_id) AS mt ON mt.transportation_claim_id = transportation_claim.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT SUM(count) AS ag_count, SUM(weight) AS ag_weight, transportation_claim_id
        FROM transportation_claim_detail
        INNER JOIN revenue_product ON revenue_product.id = revenue_product_id
        WHERE revenue_product.product_code = 'AG'
        GROUP BY transportation_claim_id) AS ag ON ag.transportation_claim_id = transportation_claim.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT SUM(count) AS ls_count, SUM(weight) AS ls_weight, transportation_claim_id
        FROM transportation_claim_detail
        INNER JOIN revenue_product ON revenue_product.id = revenue_product_id
        WHERE revenue_product.product_code = 'LS'
        GROUP BY transportation_claim_id) AS ls ON ls.transportation_claim_id = transportation_claim.id
    WHERE claim_type = 'TI'
    ORDER BY CAST(claim_no AS UNSIGNED), CAST(IFNULL(form_no, '0') AS UNSIGNED)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You gave a lot of information in your question.  The general solution to sorting text numbers as numbers is to first cast them to some numeric type.  Consider this version:

```sql
SELECT claim_no, form_no, ...
ORDER BY CAST(claim_no AS UNSIGNED), CAST(form_no AS UNSIGNED);
```

Note that if you have a persistent/repetitive need to work with the `claim_no` or `form_no` columns as numbers, it might imply that your table design should change to make these columns numeric rather than text.

Comment: As I showed in my question, I tried that solution (CASTing the fields). It made no difference. I'm working with a legacy database, pulling the data into a new system before shutting it down, so I'm not going to bother changing the field types - unless somehow that would make the ORDER BY work!